# Inquiry on comparing quadratic regression models

Tags: multiple-comparisons, polynomial, regression-strategies

I am conducting a project in which I am analyzing the relationship between stream flow and algal biomass for a 28 day interval. I have 5 different flow treatments (ranging from low to high flows). I fit regression lines (polynomial was the best fit for all), and am trying to compare slopes of the different models. I've been looking through help forums but haven't found a concrete way to compare slopes of polynomial regressions. Does anyone have any suggestions or advice on how to tackle this analysis? I thank you for your time and input.

Comment: The slope is itself another polynomial, so differentiate. The price of using polynomials is that the slope is itself a variable once you use at least a quadratic. A perk of using polynomials is that their slope is easily derived (pun intended). It goes beyond your question, but in my experience you can sometimes think of a biological (in this case) rationale for quadratics, but the only possible merit of higher-order polynomials is that they might fit well. I over-simplify, but not I think outrageously.  Regardless of that the starting-point is always a plot of data and your fitted curves.

Comment: A crucial detail is whether any turning points and inflections make sense, biologically (and/or hydrologically).  An even more crucial detail is whether any of the polynomials predict negative biomass over the range of the data or just outside. If so, they are not a good model to use.

Comment: Your title says "quadratic" (once), your text says "polynomial" (twice). I've taken the broader interpretation. Either way, "best" fit is always determined by comparing with a repertoire of the other models you tried, not determined absolutely.